# Is there an integrated software for web development that is free, or is notepad++ the way to go?

Tags: html, web, development-environment

I'm not a professional or anything, just doing this for fun.  Is there a free software suite for web development that would be better to use rather than using notepad++?

For example, I'm learning android development and I use android studio for it.

Thanks

Comment: For instance [Microsoft Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)

Comment: Sublime Text! This is much cool.

Comment: Sublime looks cool.  The Web Matrix looks really cool too.  I had to google it because the link does not seem to work for me on mobile.  Is there a catch to using it though since its a MS product and it says its free.

Comment: I find vim (or emacs) and Firefox Dev Edition or Nightly's dev console enough for what I need. vim and emacs have a rather harsh learning curve, but can be customized to fit whatever your needs are. Sublime Text is also good since it's easier to use and still has a fair amount of features.

Answer (score 0):

One option for you to consider is Microsoft's new offering, Visual Studio Code.

It's basically a free version of Visual Studio designed to be cross platform (Mac, Linux, Windows) that currently best serves ASP.NET and NodeJS.

I'd consider giving it a shot. I haven't tried it because I use Visual Studio Professional 2013 for work, which is very fully featured. But VS Code will do syntax highlighting for these:

- Batch
- C++
- Clojure
- Coffee Script
- DockerFile
- F#
- Go
- Jade
- Java
- HandleBars
- Ini
- Lua
- Makefile
- Markdown
- Objective-C
- Perl
- PHP
- PowerShell
- Python
- R
- Razor
- Ruby
- Rust
- SQL
- Visual Basic
- XML

As well as Intellisense (like autocomplete, I believe) for these:

- CSS
- HTML
- JavaScript
- JSON
- Less
- Sass

It looks like it also has some sort of built in Git support, which would be really handy. Probably worth at least considering.

https://code.visualstudio.com/